# Using Scanner on Android

Tags: java, android, file-io

Reading into file IO in Android it's clear that a lot of people recommend constructs such as the `AssetManager` or a `FileReader` for such things.

Is it possible to apply more fundamental structures like the `Scanner`? Could my use of a `Scanner` to tie txt values to Strings in my Array be the cause of my Android problems relating to File-not-found errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Scanner](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Scanner.html) in Android.
Place the text file in your assets folder, and in the code, you can access it as shown below:

```
Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(getAssets().open(String.format("yourfile.txt")));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fileReader.next(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Hey there thanks for the answer but I get the following pesky error popup for this very line of code : *The constructor File(InputStream) is undefined*, any tips?

Comment: @WilliamBrun Edited my answer, please check

Comment: I thank you from the bottom of my heart - you not only answered my question but solved the problem that has plagued me for hours, that no one has answered yet, with those two lines of code!! Thank you so so much my friend.